# Unable to Logon to server after deletion to domain and using the same name to a different server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain, login

Here is what happened. i have a server named TEST01 which is already joined to a domain. Then, i installed a new server with the same name, deleted TEST01 to domain and re-add it for the new server installed. Now I wanted to open my first TEST01 server to change its name and re add to domain, but I can't anymore. Could you tell me what to do without having to reinstall its OS?

Thank you very much guys in advance!

Comment: I have no experience with Windows Server but can't you just log in using the local administrator account ?

Comment: That is actually my problem, I can't log on even to the local administrator. I think it's because I deleted it to the domain, then use the same name to another server.

Comment: Did you disjoin it from the domain or did you simply delete the computer account in the domain? I don't understand why you can't log on as the local Administrator, can you tell us what happens when you try that? Also, disconnect the server from the network, then try to logon as the local Administrator or as a domain Administrator with cached credentials. It isn't clear from your question as to the exact state of the server.

Answer (score 2):

After you removed the computer from the domain, the domain credentials were removed from the registry cache.
This means you'll now have to use a local user.

If you don't have access to a local user, and the data on the server is critical, you can remove the new TEST01 from the domain, and run system restore using a windows disk on the old TEST01, and restore it to a joined state.

[System Restore and Domain credentials](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317049/en-us)

Edit:
Comment by TheCleaner is probably a better fit, using a boot cd such as Ultimate Boot CD is an easier solution.

Comment: If you don't have access to a local user just use something like UBCD or similar to boot and change the local administrator password.  Then reboot and login.  Easier than dealing with a restore.

Comment: Thank you for immediate response. But will this work for Windows server 2008 R2 std? Also, when i do the system restore, that means some installed applications will be removed? Thanks!

Comment: A system restore will remove application that were installed between the present time and the time the restore point was created.